# django conditional filter OR

Tags: django

```
if w:
    conditions['is_discount_table'] = 'Q( is_discount_table = True )'
    conditions['is_discount_banquet'] = 'Q( is_discount_banquet = True )'

pl = Place.objects.filter( **conditions ).order_by( 'name' )
```

SQL WHERE looks like

```
WHERE (
    "places_place"."is_discount_banquet" = true AND 
    "places_place"."is_discount_table" = true 
)
```

How to modify `w` condition that SQL WHERE looked like

```
WHERE (

        "places_place"."is_discount_banquet" = true OR
        "places_place"."is_discount_table" = true 

    )
```

equivalent of

```
Place.objects.filter( Q( is_discount_table = True ) | Q( is_discount_banquet = True ) )
```

Comment: I have some problems understanding your question. But fundamentally, Q is a Django class, so when you write it as a string in your conditions dictionary (first code block), it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: problem was in creation correct where condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer:

```
conditions_unnamed = list()
conditions_named = dict( )
if type:
    conditions_named['types__id__in'] = list_unique( type.split( '-' ) )
if w:
    conditions_unnamed.append( Q( is_discount_table = True ) | Q( is_discount_banquet = True ) )
pl = Place.objects.filter( *conditions_unnamed, **conditions_named ).order_by( 'name' )
```

if somebody knows a better solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have added some additional logic. I think this is what you are trying to express:

```
pl = Place.objects.all()
if type:
    pl = pl.filter(types__id__in=type.split( '-' ))
if w:
    pl = pl.filter( Q( is_discount_table = True ) | Q( is_discount_banquet = True ) )
pl = pl.order_by( 'name' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queres = {Q()}
...
if ...
queres.update({Q(deprecation_date__lte=datetime.date.today())})
if ...
queres.update({Q(deprecation_date=None)})
...
devices = Device.objects.filter(*queres)
```